# Target next input field present after select tag

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, razor

I have multiple section that has **dropdown** to select the product information and input field next to it to save the product information. As I will have multiple dropdown and input field I can't use **name** or **id** selector to set the value because it will affect all the input field as they share same id and class.

I tried using `closest()` but it didn't work for me. below is the section for **css/html** and **jquery**

```
@foreach(var number in totalNumber){

  <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 ml-0 pr-1">
 
   <select  name="@number"  class="form-control mb-1">

       <option>Select from the dropdown</option>
         
        @foreach(var product in @Model.ProductList){
          
            <option value="@product.productName"
                    data-pd = "@product.productDescription"
                    data-model = "@product.productModelNo">
                    @product.productName</option>
        }
            
  </select>

  <input type="hidden" class="product-name form-control mb-1" rows="1" placeholder="Product Name"/>

  <input type="hidden"  class="product-description form-control mb-1" rows="1" placeholder="Product description"/>
    
  <input type="hidden" class="product-model-number form-control mb-1" rows="1" placeholder="Product Model Number"/>
  
 </div>
}
```

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var productName = this.value;
    var productDescription = $(this).data("pd");
    var productModelNo = $(this).data("model");
    $(this).closest('input').find(".product-name").val(productName);
    $(this).closest('input').find(".product-description").val(productDescription);
    $(this).closest('input').find(".product-model-number").val(productModelNo);
});
```

Comment: this is not an asp or razor question. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] using just Script, HTML and CSS

Comment: Then change `$(this).closest('input').` to `$(this).closest('div').` since closest goes for PARENT elements